# Uso de "Xp" como "crist" en el siglo XVII

Tags: pronunciación, historia, deletreo, genealogía

En la partida de nacimiento de mi antepasado Alejo Saiz (abuelo del tatarabuelo de mi tatarabuelo en línea directa paterna, nacido en 1645, quien dio origen al apellido Alejo en mi rama familiar), se puede ver lo siguiente:

[image: Xpobal]

Cuesta un poco de leer, pero la línea del centro dice "hijo de Xpobal". La transcripción de la partida lo entiende (y así lo confirma una búsqueda rápida por Internet) como "Cristóbal" según la denominación actual del nombre.

Entiendo que la "X" se usa desde hace tiempo como "cris", como aún se lee en términos como el inglés "Xmas". Sin embargo, me despista que lo siguiera una "p" después.

¿El grupo "Xp" debía entenderse como "crist"? En caso afirmativo, ¿a qué se debía esto? ¿O es que el nombre se pronunciaba diferente en el siglo XVII? ¿O es que lo que hay detrás de la "X" no es una "p"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ni X ni p, en realidad; el símbolo Xp que podemos ver en muchos sitios como representación de *Cristo* es una simple adaptación al alfabeto latino de las dos primeras letras del nombre griego de Cristo, Χριστός.

Son las mismas letras que se utilizan en el *crismón* o monograma de Cristo:

[image]

Hay otro monograma también muy utilizado para Cristo, JHS, que también tiene su origen en una latinización del nombre griego. En este caso, está formado por las tres primeras letras del nombre Jesús en griego (ΙΗΣΟΥΣ -> ΙΗΣ), adaptadas a IHS y de ahí, al aparecer la J en el alfabeto latino (recordemos que originalmente no existía), a JHS. En efecto, la H de ese monograma no es sino la letra griega eta mayúscula, convertida a la latina H por su parecido gráfico, del mismo modo que las ji-ro del crismón se han convertido en equis-pe latinas por semejanza gráfica y no por equivalencia fonética.

[image]

Comment: +1 porque está muy bien dicho y +1 por lo conciso. Sólo creo que no sobra agregar que las letras son chi (pronunciada como la j castellana) y rho.

Comment: Existe en Unicode: ☧ Así puede ser más pequeño ;-)

Comment: @walen No sé cómo poner el gráfico más pequeño, la verdad es que ha quedado enorme :D

Comment: @Rafael O, más exactamente en español, ji y ro.

Comment: @walen de hecho no hace falta usar HTML: cuando subes una imagen en [se], automáticamente hay unos sufijos con reducción. [¿Es posible re-dimensionar una imagen en una publicación?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1138/83)

Comment: @walen caramba, ahí me ha fallado lo de redimensionar. ¡Gracias!